# Alternative for shortest_path algorithm

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have a network consisting of 335 nodes. I computed the `weighted shortest.paths` between all of the nodes.
Now I would like to see which path sequences where used to travel between the nodes.

I use the the `shortest_path` command in igraph and iterate through all combinations of nodes in my network (335² combinations - 335(path from/to same node is 0)/2 (graph is undirected). So all in all I have to iterate over 55.945 combinations.

My approach looks like this:
`net` is my network
`sp_data` is a df with all combinations of links in the network

```
results1 <- sapply(sp_data[,1], function(x){shortest_paths(net, from = x, to = V(net), output="epath"})
```

Unfortunately this needs ages to compute and at the end I don't have enough memory to store the information. (`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 72 Kb`).
Basically I have two questions:

1. How can it be that the `shortest.paths` command needs seconds to compute the distance between all nodes of my network whereas extracting the path sequences (not just it length) needs days and exceeds the memory capacity?
2. Is there an alternative to get the desired output (path sequences of shortest path)? I guess that the `sapply` Syntax should already be faster than a `for::loop`?

Comment: try using travelling salesman problem

Comment: Can you recommend a package?

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/travelling-salesman-with-ggmap/  and https://gist.github.com/kandebonfim/09b1ed8a9fcc3e5e62b389acb3df0ec1

Answer (score 0):

you could try [cppRouting](https://github.com/vlarmet/cppRouting) package. 
It provides `get_multi_paths` function which return a list containing the node sequence for each shortest path.

```
library(igraph)
library(cppRouting)

#random graph
g <- make_full_graph(335) 

#convert to three columns data.frame 
df<-data.frame(igraph::as_data_frame(g),dist=1) 

#instantiate cppRouting graph
gr<-cppRouting::makegraph(df) 

#extract all nodes 
all_nodes<-unique(c(df$from,df$to))

#Get all paths sequence
all_paths<-get_multi_paths(Graph=gr,from=all_nodes,to=all_nodes)

#Get path from node 1 to 3
all_paths[["1"]][["3"]]
```